# Spices become wet and clumpy once I start cooking

Tags: seasoning, spicy-hot, chicken-breast

Lately, whenever I've been cooking food like chicken breasts or hamburgers, after I'm done seasoning them and set them on the pan, once I flip the food over I notice the seasoning gets really wet and starts clumping together or it sticks to the pan and dries up. It didn't happen a few months ago but for the past 5 weeks it has. I've tried cooking at different temperatures and difderent pans but nothing works. I've looked it this problem everywhere yet I never find an answer.

Comment: Could you add some more information, please? What sort of seasonings are you adding? Putting them in a pan means you're frying them? How much fat do you use and what type? Has the weather changed a great deal from 5 weeks back? All these details can help us understand better since we're not there personally to witness what's happening.

Comment: Are you seasoning dry meat? Adding a small amount of oil before seasoning might help it stick better to steak and chicken... usually hamburger you work the seasoning into the hamburger before forming patties.

Answer (score 2):

If searing the meat in the pan, then once you put the seasoned meat in the pan, do not move it. Leave it in position until you flip it to avoid the seasoning rubbing off onto the pan or clumping.